# How to retrieve UPN(User principal Name) of current logged in user using Java

Tags: java, windows, active-directory, jaas, waffle

I want to retrieve UserPrincipalName of current logged in user using java.I can connect to AD and retrieve that, but i want to avoid all those configuration and other stuff, is there an easier way to get UPN using java?

UPN stored in AD is usually in userName@domainName format. If my user is john and domain is vmware, it should return john@vmware.

Please advise.

Comment: `JavaScript` is not `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

Java and JavaScript are separate languages. For a java servlet you can get the UserPrinciple name property with

```
GetPageContext().getRequest().getUserPrincipal().getName()
```

For javascript you'd need to have the server provide this via rendering it as a value, or have some framework or AJAX that allows the user principle be added to the response data or callable via the page script.